# Name for a Boolean ring without a unit element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, boolean-algebra

Is there a standard name for a Boolean ring without a unit?

I read that historically *ring* and *Boolean ring* used to refer to possibly non-unital objects:

> The old terminology was to use "Boolean ring" to mean a "Boolean ring possibly without an identity" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring
>
> Back in the day, the term ‘ring’ meant a possibly nonunital ring; that is a semigroup, rather than a monoid, in Ab. This terminology applied also to Boolean rings, and it changed even more slowly. -- http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Boolean+ring

Now that the name *ring* commonly assumes a unit element, is there a shorter name for a "possibly non-unital Boolean ring"

Comment: Actually, the definition of a ring does not require a unital element. (I just looked it up in Van der Waerden to make sure my memory isn't playing tricks.) The difference between a Boolean ring and a Boolean algebra is that the latter must have a unital element.

Comment: The ncatlab article is from the viewpoint of a category theorist, so that explains its preference that all rings are unital. The Wikipedia article was just unfortunately worded, and I have since revised it. Although it is indeed historical usage, that turns out to be still commonplace usage in the present day. There is no reason not to use "boolean ring."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since "rng" is standard for "ring without assuming an identity", "Boolean rng" seems a reasonable name that's likely to be understood, even though it doesn't seem to have been used much in the literature.

Comment: I just came up with the same idea and was going to update the question, only to find out that you were faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When I perform a Google books search for "Boolean ring", a majority of the top two pages of hits explicitly do not assume identity. The same is still true when restricting to hits with publication dates in the past decade. So it seems like a standard usage of **boolean ring** fits your requirements quite well already.

Naturally you are going to find category theorists preferring the version with identity, but this is not really conclusive evidence of a coherent trend. If you had come across sources written by operator algebraists, you would not have been lead down this path.

I did run into the same convention [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=RRZtCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA19&dq=%22Boolean+ring%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwCDgKahUKEwiesYaGu7LIAhVBmR4KHVrhA9k#v=onepage&q=%22Boolean%20ring%22&f=false), though. It reserves the term "Boolean *algebra*" for Boolean rings with identity. This is sensible because it can be considered as an algebra over the field of two elements only when a (unital) embedding of the field into the ring can be achieved.